# Hi I'm new to dart and flutter I do not know why this isnt working, nothing happens when the button is pressed and I have no clue why

Tags: flutter, dart

> New to this so I have no clue whats wrong here. I need the code to add 1 to _count when the button is pressed but nothing happens when the button is pressed

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int _count = 0;
void main() {
  var app = MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _count++;
          return _count.toString();
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Welcome')),
      body: Center(
      child: Text('You have pressed the button $_count times.'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  runApp(app);
}
```

Comment: You need to use [`setState`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive).

Comment: @Abion47 without StatefulWidget?

Comment: You have no state management in there, use `StatefulWidget` class for this, or some package that handles state without it, like [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Answer (score 1):

To update state you need `StatefulWiget` to have a state with your count data, then call [`setState`](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) when you change your data:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState((){_count++;}); 
          
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Welcome')),
      body: Center(
      child: Text('You have pressed the button $_count times.'),
      ),
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

You can fast check result copying this code to [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) and pressing run.

It will be good start for you if you check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) page, knowing what is state in flutter.